# Oil Light Flickered ... Have I Destroyed My Engine?

Tags: toyota, camry, oil-leak

This happened on an 02 Toyota Camry. I had an oil leak, the oil light flickered on off. I added two quarts of oil to it. This happened three different times over 800 miles. The oil light would just flicker on and off occasionally. I wasn’t aware there was a leak until it was too late. The car doesn’t seem to have any problems, but should i ditch it while i can or hold onto it? How much damage could have been done?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. But I would fill oil to proper level and drive it. Check out unusual sounds. Otherwise to tear down the engine to evaluate all possible abnormal wear would cost a large fraction of the cost of an engine rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

If the oil light only flickered a few times on an 800 mile journey and adding some oil has stopped it happening, then I would say you will have not caused any additional damage.

The flicker would likely have happened when the low oil level in the sump moved away from the oil pump pickup due to cornering/braking.  A very brief low oil pressure indicated by the warning lamp is unlikely to cause damage.  If the warning lamp was lit for a few seconds at a time, then you could have started getting into a dangerous situation for the engine.

I would just keep an eye on the oil level.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing your engine any favors, but you probably haven't killed it irreparably.

When you have less oil, the oil that is in there is running hotter and going through the engine more often.  That's not good for the oil's life. So you should change it a lot more often, but from the sound of things, *you are* lol.

However, the oil light doesn't indicate oil level. It indicates oil *pressure* has fallen below 1/3 of normal. For pressure to fall, there's so little oil that the oil pump is starting to suck air - all the working oil is up in the galleries or starting to drip down, and isn't filling the sump enough to fully feed the oil pump.

Most engines are set up so the "bottom end" (the crankshaft) gets oil *first*. That means most likely the crank and pistons were getting sufficient oil.  The cylinder head parts might be a little starved, but they also have less stress on them and if push comes to shove, it's much easier to replace a head than a block.

So I say: engine block damage vanishingly unlikely, cylinder head damage also quite unlikely. You caught it in the nick of time.  Yes, when oil light flickers, fill at first opportunity.

A "hard on" oil light calls for *immediate* engine shutdown and call for tow.  *If you must use power to guide the car to a place of safety, expect the engine to be slagged - your first thought should be **"Engines are cheaper than human lives"***.

However, if you have the situation, confidence, skill and muscle-memory to get out of gear, shut the engine down immediately *and coast* to a place of safety, then by all means do that.  That will prevent further damage to the engine.   Last time I had that problem, someone had changed the oil filter and not realized the last filter's gasket was still on the engine, so the filter was double gasketed. This took a whole day to fail, for some reason!

IMO, a competent driver should frequently practice shifting into neutral without overshooting and getting into reverse (trick: *do not push the button* and it should just land in neutral). Do it often, so it becomes muscle memory: when approaching a traffic light you'll be at for awhile, or when stopped with pedestrians crossing in front of you, so the car can't drift into them.  Twitching the ignition off for long enough to cut the engine, then back on is another good skill - turning the ignition back on will bring back instruments and electric power assists. (increasingly, steering and brakes).  It also helps to be experienced with how power steering will fade with the engine or ignition off, and how brakes will require more pressure if used 2-3 times after engine shutdown.